# Bayonets in a world without the city of Bayonne

Tags: alternate-history

Supposedly, the bladed or spiked weapon which fits on the end of a firearm derives its name from the French city of Bayonne. In a world (described in modern English) with no link or knowledge of the city, what might the rifle attachment be called?

Similarly, what would the [mounting mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount) (for light bulbs, for example) deriving its name from the bayonet be called?

Comment: There is Bayonne, New Jersey ;)

Comment: Names are highly opinion based. It could be whatever.

Comment: "[What is the best name for X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130#6259)" questions are off-topic as they are always [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).

Comment: It would probably be named after the inventor.

Comment: Probably would've been called a glaive or a fauchard - both names used for the medieval polearm mounted blade. I'd hazard that glaive, being shorter and punchier a sound would've been the word of choice over time.

Answer (score 14):

Well obviously it would be called

### [The Rooty Tooty Stab and Shooty](https://youtu.be/NOOkH-bZQyk)

But seriously though, it could be anything. If it were invented in Boston, it could equivalently be called the Bostoner. Or people could be really boring and call it a rifle knife. Ooh I know! **[Gunblade!](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Gunblade_(weapon_type))**

Comment: Perhaps the "Bang-Bang Stab-Stab"?

Answer (score 3):

A blade fixed to a rifle barrel would probably just be referred to as a fixed blade or [knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet). This is similar to how Kleenex is a brand name facial tissue, and Scotch Tape is a brand of masking tape. In my area of the world, these items are commonly referred to as Kleenex and Scotch tape respectively, despite having a generic name.

I feel that this is just as likely to be the case as it being referred to by another locales [name](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/141856/40234).